# how to call variable in next page

Tags: php, database, variables, mysqli

Am getting Notice: Undefined index: getdobcval in C:\xampp\htdocs\bgtest\buy_test.php on line 11

Am trying call variable, how to call variable from page1.php to page2.php

am using below form action

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="getdobcval">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

when user click submit value, it'l store the value in database and show the values in same page, i used page redirectory option after function finish (after 5 seconds). page redirectory working but after page am getting error

how to call  `<input type="text" name="getdobcval">` value ?

this is my database

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){                                                    

$getdob_cval = $_POST['getdobtcval'];                                               

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bgtest");
$sql = "INSERT INTO bgtest(getdobtcval) VALUES('$getdob_cval')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    echo "Please wait, We are redirecting another page!";
    echo '<script> setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.href="buy_test.php"
        },3000);
     </script>';
}else{
    echo "error";
 }      
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"call"* a variable? Getting the value of variable? If yes, have you tried `$_POST['getdobcval']`

Comment: You will need to load it from your database.  **In order to give an answer**, you'll need to share with us how you save it to your database, so we can construct an answer that is consistent with your DB structure.

Comment: Save the value in a database with some kind of a token id. Then use the token id on any page to read back from the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done via a server-side script. Let's say **script.php**

```
<form action = "script.php"...
```

Or make sure that

```
<form action = ""...
```

Is specified in from on a .PHP page itself.

When the script refreshes, the values will be available via following array:

```
<?php
    $a = $_POST["getdobcval"];  // Submitted as POST
    $b = $_GET["getdobcval"];    // Submitted as GET
?>
```

Or alternatively you can receive it regardless of how it was submitted by:

```
<?php
    $c = $_REQUEST["getdobcval"];
?>
```

Comment: actually i am executing two functions,   i used action="" empty because am executing first value in same page , after function execute page will redirect to page2.php , so next page am getting above error , am trying to call same variable in two pages

Comment: I will rewrite the answer to help ya out, But I need more info. What is the exact error you receive when the call returns?

Comment: Then you can store it in either localStorage or retrieve it by ID. What's the issue / actual error?

Comment: Have you tried storing it in a session and checking if it is set in the page you're redirecting to?

Comment: how to store input value into session ? am new to php any suggestion please

Comment: Call session_start() at the very top of each PHP page on which you want your session variable become available. Then to set it use session array $_SESSION["name"] = "value"; Now, even after you refresh the page in browser this $_SESSION["name"] should contain original value. As long as you call session_start() at the very top of the script, you should be able to have read/write access to it. More info https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp